# How to handling emoticons in Android

Tags: android, emoticons

i am working on an instant chat application in android.I have done with the basic functionality like sending messages from one mobile to another and from web application to mobile application.Now i am adding some extra feature in my app . i am adding emoticons in my app . i am using library compile 'com.rockerhieu.emojicon:library:1.3.3' to add emoticons .
I am getting problems while using this library.Emoticon which i select is changed after sending.Screen shot are given for the help .

**ScreenShot**
[image: Image 1 Selecting emotiocons]

[image: Image 2 After being sent]

[image: Image 3]

[image: image 4]

**activity_chat.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FCAB26"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view_messages"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".60"
    android:background="@null"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"></ListView>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight=".10"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText
        android:id="@+id/edtMessage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight=".70"></com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSendMessage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight=".30"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Send Message" />
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/emojicons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".30" />
```

**ChatActivity.java**

Below is the part of code that is handling emoticons:

```
    public class ChatActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        EmojiconGridFragment.OnEmojiconClickedListener, EmojiconsFragment.OnEmojiconBackspaceClickedListener {

    EmojiconEditText edMessage = (EmojiconEditText) findViewById(R.id.edtMessage);
 @Override
    public void onEmojiconBackspaceClicked(View view) {
        EmojiconsFragment.backspace(edMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEmojiconClicked(Emojicon emojicon) {
        EmojiconsFragment.input(edMessage, emojicon);
    }

}
```

Please tell me how can i handle this issue.When i am selecting an emoticon from the list of emoticons provided by the library compile 'com.rockerhieu.emojicon:library:1.3.3' ,it id getting changed in the view.What should i do to handle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are android defaults, which you see when entered, to use the emoji's like as they are, you need to create your own implementation by mapping all the png files, have a look at 
[Madhur's example](https://github.com/madhur/android-chat-starter) he has implemented Whatsapp(Old version Non material) like app, for beginners to learn.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Veer3389 . I have fixed my issue.Actually i have to use  EmojiconTextView  instead of TextView to display the emoticon selected.Now i ma getting what i am selecting through the list of emoticons.But one problem is there when i am entering :-),corresponding image is not displayed.I hope ur link will help me,

Comment: yes, EmojiTextView is required, that what he has implemented, i guess yes it should be helpful.